# Get full path from command line in assembly

Tags: assembly, unicode, command-line, path, nasm

I've been torturing myself with this issue for a month and I'm about to give up. It is a simple program and I just can't see why is not working properly.
So, what I am trying to do create is a simple application that will parse the command line and display the first argument, which is the full path to the executable.
This is how my code looks like:

```
use32

[EXTERN GetStdHandle]
[EXTERN GetCommandLineW]
[EXTERN WriteConsoleW]
[EXTERN ExitProcess]

[section .bss]
StdHandle resd 1
PathStart resw 1
PathEnd resw 1
WrittenChars resw 1

[section .data]
message db __utf16__("Hello everybody"), 13, 10, 0

[section .text]
global start

start:
    call GetHandler
    call GetCommandLine
    end:
        mov eax, 0
        ret

    GetHandler:
        push -11
        call GetStdHandle
        cmp eax, 1
        push ebx
        mov ebx, 1
        jl CloseApp
        pop ebx
        mov dword[StdHandle], eax
        ret

    GetCommandLine:
        cld
        call GetCommandLineW ; UNICODE
        mov esi, eax
        mov bh, 0 ; here we save the argc
        mov ecx, eax ; here we save the pointer of the first arg

        Parse:
            lodsw
            cmp ax, __utf16__(' ')
            je NewArg
            jmp ContinueParsing

            NewArg:
                inc bh
                cmp bh, 1
                jne Parse
                ; if the first arg was just read save the 
                ; start from ecx and end from esi to the BSS variables
                mov dword[PathStart], ecx
                mov dword[PathEnd], esi
                jmp ShowPath

        ContinueParsing:
            cmp ax, 0
            jne Parse

        ShowPath:
            mov ecx, [PathEnd]
            mov ebx, [PathStart]
            sub ecx, ebx ; text size
            shr ecx, 1 ; is UNICODE
            push dword[PathStart]
            push dword[ecx]
            call ShowText
            ret

    ShowText:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        push 0
        push dword WrittenChars
        push dword [ebp+8]
        push dword [ebp+12]
        push dword [StdHandle]
        call WriteConsoleW
        pop ebp
        ret 8

    CloseApp:
        push ebx
        call ExitProcess
        pop ebx
        ret
```

Well, I might have misspelled or missed something but that is not the problem. The code is compiled and built successfully but the message that I see is only the name of the executable, not the full path that I expect. If the full path is *"D:\My Projects\NASM\Demo.exe"* I only see *"Demo"*. If before calling `ShowText` I prepare the arguments for the `message` variable it works and I can see the text correctly, so I think the problem lies in getting the pointer and length of the full path correctly. Yet, when studying the running of the application with *OllyDbg* I can see that correct values are stored in the `BSS` section. This is very weird and maybe somebody with a better eye can catch the cause of it. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE** 
Today I tried to display the entire command line like this:

```
GetCommandLine:
        cld
        call GetCommandLineW ; UNICODE
        mov esi, eax
        ; display it here
        push    dword       eax
        push    dword       128
        call    ShowText
```

and I still see weird characters. I know there are alternatives but I just want to know why something so easy at a first sight is not working. I mean, computers don't do things at random and without explanation.

Comment: The full path of _what_? Could you give an example command line and the output you expect?

Comment: The command line contains the path to the executable and other arguments that the user specifies. Example: "C:\Program Files\MyApp\AppExe.exe" "arg1" "arg2". From here I want to display only the first part (the full path to the executable), which is "C:\Program Files\MyApp\AppExe.exe"

Comment: The path you're testing contains a space (between _My_ and _Projects_). Your parsing code doesn't handle such cases properly.

Comment: You probably want to look into calling [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx). That does the parsing for you, correctly handling spaces in quoted arguments, escape characters, etc.

Comment: I could use that as a last option yet it is frustrating to see that something so simple doesn't work. Even if it would stop at the first space, at least I should see the text until that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `jne Parse  ; Otherwise, continue parsing`
>     `mov dword [PathStart], ecx  ; Save the start of the path's string`
>     `mov dword [PathEnd], esi  ; Save the end of the path's string`
>     `ContinueParsing:`
>     `cmp ax, 0  ; If this is not the end of the command-line`
>     `jne Parse  ; go back to Parse`

After `mov dword [PathEnd], esi` you should `jmp` to `ShowPath`. Otherwise you'll end up checking if `ax == 0` - which it obviously won't be since it contains a space character - and you'll end up back at `Parse`.

---

> `mov ecx, [PathStart]  ; Save the start of the path's string in ECX`
>     `mov ebx, [PathEnd]  ; Save the end of the path's string in EBX`
>     `sub ecx, ebx  ; Calculate the size of the path's string in ECX`

You're subtracting `PathEnd` from `PathStart`. It should be the other way around. You'll also need to divide the length by two (i.e. `shr ecx,1`) before calling `WriteConsoleW`, since the third argument to `WriteConsoleW` is the number of characters to write (not number of bytes).

---

It might also be a good idea to add a `cld` instruction at the beginning of `GetFullPath` to make sure that `lodsw` moves the address in the correct direction.

Comment: weird that it still doesn't work. only "MyApp" is displayed. Wrong start, wrong length

Comment: It works for me (I used masm32 to confirm that my suggested changes gave the desired result).